# file_get_contents stopped working

Tags: php, facebook, file-get-contents

I have a php script on my site http://searchisback.com which used to work to retrieve a bit of text from the public page of a user. This code, which used to grab my Facebook page, no longer does so. Any ideas why?

```
$url = "http://facebook.com/michael.morgenstern";
$options = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"GET",
    'header'=>"Accept-language: en\r\n" .
              "Cookie: foo=bar\r\n" . 
              "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; U; CPU OS 3_2 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/531.21.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.4 Mobile/7B334b Safari/531.21.102011-10-16 20:23:10\r\n" // i.e. An iPad 
  )
);

$context = stream_context_create($options);

$file = @file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

echo $file;
```

Thank you!

Michael

Comment: Scraping Facebook is against their ToS (unless you have their explicit prior written consent) - so you have been doing it wrong all along, even when it was “working.” You need to use the API.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the @ it suppresses warnings

```
PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(http://facebook.com/michael.morgenstern)
HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
```

Comment: Thanks! It looks like Facebook is returning a 404 in response to this query, but not in response to browser queries. Not sure how to get it.

Answer (score -1):

try `https` instead of `http`

```
https://www.facebook.com/michael.morgenstern
```

best regards (and some good things to fill 30 characters)